# Catch exception in DB2 function

Tags: db2, exception, db2-9.7

I want to catch exception in DB2 function and return 0 if there was an exception.
I don't know how the right syntax

```
create function is_decimal(c_data varchar(100))
RETURNS INTEGER
begin
    select cast(c_data as decimal(12,10)) from sysibm.sysdummy1;

    return 1;

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
    return 0;
end
```

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at examples in the manual?

Comment: Yeah but it keep failing me

Comment: If you look at the syntax diagram, you may notice that all `DECLARE` statements must precede any executable statements. Besides, a `SELECT` in compound SQL must be `INTO` something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @mustaccio pointed out, you need to select into something, and you need to declare the handler before the actual code. Something like:

```
create or replace function is_decimal(c_data varchar(100))
RETURNS INTEGER
begin
    declare t decimal(12,10);
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING BEGIN return 0; END;
    select cast(c_data as decimal(12,10)) into t from sysibm.sysdummy1;
    return 1;
end @
```

should work. I used @ as a statement terminator